# Regex to find uppercase and lowercase and any derived words

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove `word` in my string:

```
Word , WOrd , WORd , wORd , word , WoRd
```

I researched about it, but can't find a way to achieve this. How can I write the regular expression for this?

Comment: just google for case sensitivity flag.

Comment: you've  been searching and you haven't found the case-insensitive flag? What were you looking for and where?

Comment: you can change the case sensitivity for the regex match.

Comment: @M.Eskandari: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking how to remove all the variations of `words` from your string? Or something different? Please edit your question and **include expected output** and **what you have tried so far**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `/i` modifier to ignore the case.

```
$input = preg_replace("/word/i", "", $input);
```

Comment: hopefully it's not an article about s**word**s.

Comment: it's ok! Are you known whats refrence for regex and more samples??

Comment: @M.Eskandari: http://regular-expressions.info is pretty good. If you're looking for a book, you can try "Mastering Regular Expressions".

Answer (score 1):

see the following example from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
<?php
// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search
if (preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want but here goes...

```
$words = "Word , WOrd , WORd , wORd , word , WoRd";
$wordArray = explode(",", $words);

foreach($wordArray  as $key=>$word){
    if($word==strtolower($word)){
        unset($wordArray[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Best answer. +1. Got downvoted probably just due to 10 more oPTioNs missing.